# How can one pause a backgound video based on scrolling down the page?

Tags: html, video

I have a generic sample site over at http://matiny.tk/warframesite/index.html
What I would like to know is how I'd be able to pause the video when the user scrolls down the page. In other words, when the #content div (the white space) has taken up (let's say) 75% of the screen, the video pauses.
Thanks!

Comment: Easy! Bind a scroll event listener and determine when the `#content` element has covered 75% of the screen. Once it has, your callback will call `pause()` for the video element (like: `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].pause()`) - Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does. Of course I gotta do more research on JS, since I still don't get the usage of [ ]s.

Comment: When you do: `document.getElementsByTagName()`, it will return an array-like object (a NodeList) of all the elements in the DOM that matches the tag name. You use `[]` to reference which element you want to select. IF you give the video an `id` and use `document.getElementById()`, you can reference the returned object directly (since IDs are unique and `getElementById` will return the element directly).

Comment: And 0 refers to the 1st. Gotcha.

Comment: Here's a quick fiddle I threw together: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uaxkr2pw/show/ and the script for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/uaxkr2pw/

Comment: Updated with a quicker loading (but crappier) video: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uaxkr2pw/3/show/

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is only functional in Chrome.

Comment: You're right - here's one that's a bit more cross browser friendly: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uaxkr2pw/6/show/ (swapped out document.body.scrollTop for window.pageYOffset)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although, the fact that you tell me that this is simple tells me that I'm way behind my JS learning. I'll get on that post haste.

Comment: No problem! Once you've spruced up your JS, I recommend checking out jQuery. It's designed to remove all of the multi-browser ticky tack headaches (such as how to determine offsets, event bindings, and things like that) that complicate things. Good luck man!